# Laravel 4.2 | construct beforeFilter - auth check

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, before-filter

I've got this code:

```
function __construct() {
  $this->beforeFilter('auth');

  if (Auth::user()->hasRole('A')) {
    return \Redirect::route('B')->send();
  }
}

Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('auth/login');
            die();
        }
    }
});
```

---

And the result is this error:

> Call to a member function hasRole() on null

The auth filter should redirect me automatically to auth page. But it doesn't do that until it finished the all function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: it seems like you're not authenticated into the application. Are you using some sort of library to auth?

Comment: Its laravel basic auth library, the purpose of the `beforeFilter` function is to drop me to the login page if the auth check is failed. But it doesn't drop me until the construct function end's - so I get this error.

Comment: can you post your `beforeFilter` function?

Comment: Of course, I've posted it on the main message.

Comment: See if changing the `Auth::guest()` line to `Auth::check()` in your `auth` filter fixes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is the solution:

```
function __construct() 
{
  if ($this->beforeFilter('auth')) {
    if (Auth::user()->hasRole('A')) {
      return \Redirect::route('B')->send();
    }
  }
}
```